# Splitting DataFrame column from a referenced list of values

Tags: python, string, pandas, split, data-cleaning

I've a pandas DataFrame (list of video games)  with a column "classification". In that column, we can find:

- simple classification: "RPG" or "Action"
- multiple classifications: "Action Adventure RPG Roguelike", "Action Shoot'em Up Wargame"

You have noticed? There is **no separator**...

Of course, I need to split this in a new column, WITH separator (Or other structure with each separate element).

So

```
"Action Adventure RPG Roguelike" => "Action, Adventure, RPG, Roguelike"
"Action Shoot'em Up Wargame" => "Action, Shoot'em Up, Wargame"
```

I can't use space to split, nor Caps ("`Shoot'em Up`" is ONE value).

So, in my mind, I need to create a function to apply to this column, and check from a list of values (made by hand), find all of occurrence and return the string with separator...

Something like that:

```
classification = ["Action", "Adventure", "RPG", "Roguelike", "Shoot'em Up", "Wargame"...]

def magic_tric(data):
   # do the magic, comparing each classification possible / data
   return data_separated
```

But I do not know how to do it. In the most efficient way...

Can someone help me...?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an idea..using `str.findall`

```
                                0
0  Action Adventure RPG Roguelike
1      Action Shoot'em Up Wargame

sep = ["Action", "Adventure", "RPG", "Roguelike", "Shoot'em Up", "Wargame"]
pattern = '|'.join(sep)


pd.DataFrame(df[0].str.findall(pattern).tolist())
```

---

```
        0            1        2          3
0  Action    Adventure      RPG  Roguelike
1  Action  Shoot'em Up  Wargame       None
```

Comment: Yes ! You are my hero of the day :-)

Comment: @Richnou also consider accepting the answer if you found it useful..thanks.